# pyeval not working on vim -u NONE or vim diffs

Tags: neovim, vimscript-python

`:echo pyeval('vim.current.window.col')` works fine on a normal Neovim instance.

But if I start Neovim in diff mode or with the `-u NONE` option and try the same command, I get this error:

```
Error detected while processing function provider#python#Call:
line   18:
NameError("name 'vim' is not defined",)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neovim/msgpack_rpc/session.py", line 181, in handler
    rv = self._request_cb(name, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neovim/api/common.py", line 237, in filter_request_cb
    walk(self._in, args, self, name, 'request'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neovim/plugin/host.py", line 69, in _on_request
    rv = handler(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neovim/plugin/script_host.py", line 148, in python_eval
    return eval(expr, self.module.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'vim' is not defined
0
```

Any idea why this is happening? Not sure if this is related to Vim in general or Neovim.

Comment: Did you try adding `import vim`?

Comment: Great that was the problem! I guess I should to read the vim python doc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Carpetsmoker's comment, the solution was as simple as doing a
`:python import vim` first.

The relevant doc is at `:h python-vim`.